# Different JRE installations (windows)

Tags: java, installation, registry

When I download and install Java 8 (JRE) from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
I can see the folowing registry key: 
[**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\**Java Runtime Environment**]
"CurrentVersion"="1.8"

However if I download and install Java 8 (JRE) from:
https://www.java.com/en/download/
I got the following registry key:
[**HKEY_CURRENT_USER**\Software\JavaSoft\**DeploymentProperties**]

1. I need to detect if Java 8 (JRE) is installed, should I check them both? Are there other registry location I need to check?
2. What’s are the differences between the two installers? Are they both providing the same Java JRE or there are any differences?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would try different approach, try look for java(w).exe on system variable PATH. It should point to latest installation of JRE - assuming latest directory entry in PATH.

Also if your application require specific JVM then its also possible to include JRE with your application. Just pack it inside and make sure your JRE is started. Many companies doing it for very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider 32bit installations on a 64 bit machine as well.

In Microsoft's techNet site I found a *vbs* script to be used to determine the java version. Hope it helps. [TechNet article on determining the version of java on windows](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/598.script-to-determine-java-version.aspx)